# Installation of the cutils package

Tags: python

I am trying to install this particular tool called RGT-TDF
It says while installing that the pysam.cutils module is missing. So I am trying to install the cutils package. when trying to run the make install command it gives me a syntax error in the setup.py file which says the following:

file "setup.py", line 39
    script, option, *folders= sys.argv[]
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

could someone help me in solving this?

Comment: This might be better suited on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) than here...